# Makefile.am contains errors related to tabs

Tags: linux

im trying to run the make cmd but i keep getting a this missing seperator error. i know it has to do with "tabs" but i am not seeing the error. can someone point me to where and what is causing this error. i attached the make file bellow

```
# -*- Makefile -*-

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS  = -I m4
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects

SUBDIRS          = libiptc libxtables
if ENABLE_DEVEL
SUBDIRS         += include
endif
if ENABLE_LIBIPQ
SUBDIRS         += libipq
endif
SUBDIRS         += utils
# Depends on libxtables:
SUBDIRS         += extensions
# Depends on extensions/libext.a:
SUBDIRS         += iptables

if ENABLE_NFTABLES
confdir         = $(sysconfdir)
dist_conf_DATA  = etc/ethertypes
endif

.PHONY: tarball
tarball:
        rm -Rf /tmp/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION};
        pushd ${top_srcdir} && git archive --prefix=${PACKAGE_TARNAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}/ HEAD | tar -C /tmp -x && popd;
        pushd /tmp/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION} && ./autogen.sh && popd;
        tar --exclude=*.t --exclude=iptables-test.py -C /tmp -cjf ${PACKAGE_TARNAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}.tar.bz2 --owner=root --group=root ${PACKAGE_TARNAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}/;
        rm -Rf /tmp/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION};

config.status: extensions/GNUmakefile.in \
        include/xtables-version.h.in include/iptables/internal.h.in
```

Comment: You'll get this error if tabs were converted to spaces.  You have to go through each line that starts with what you think is a tab and make sure it actually is a tab and not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is probably converting tabs to spaces. You didn't state what editor you're using but try to configure it to not convert tabs to spaces.